# How to convert a dirset value into a string

Tags: ant

I am writing a javascript ant task using scriptdef:

```
<scriptdef name="xxx" language="javascript">
    <element name="dirset" type="dirset"/>
    <![CDATA[
      importClass(java.io.File);
      var dirsets = elements.get("dirset");
      var t = dirsets.get(0);
      self.log(t.indexOf("T"));
    ]]>
</scriptdef>
```

When I run this script, it complains that it can't find the indexOf function.  Any ideas?

Comment: use => self.log(t.toString().indexOf("T")); instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) ANT task:

```
<pathconvert property="dirs.str" pathsep=" " refid="dirset.id"/>
```